# Python calculated Timedelta 50 years in future, should be same day

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, timedelta

This is a follow up to [Calculating new column value in dataframe based on next rows column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66683405/calculating-new-column-value-in-dataframe-based-on-next-rows-column-value)

The solution in the previous question worked for a column holding hh:mm:ss values as a string.

I tried applying (no pun intended) the same logic to calculate the 1 second difference on a column of pandas Timestamps:

```
# df.start_time is now of type <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
# in yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss format
s = pd.to_timedelta(df.start_time).shift(-1).sub(pd.offsets.Second(1))
df = df.assign( end_time=s.add(pd.Timestamp('now').normalize()).dt.time.astype(str) )
```

By mistake in one round of coding I change the line where the series is applied as a column to the df to:

```
df = df.assign( end_time=s.add(pd.Timestamp('now').normalize()))
```

The results were... interesting. The end_time is in the correct format, but the date portion...

```
    start_time                   end_time
2021-03-30 16:58:13     2072-06-28 03:17:30.192227
2021-03-30 17:00:00     2072-06-28 03:17:32.192227
```

I expected the end_time Timedelta of 1 second less than the start_time.  As you can see that is not the case!  The end_time Timedelta is 51 years in the future!

Can someone please explain how/why this happened?  There is no explicit call of `pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=50)`

Comment: I did not want a Timedelta 51 years into the future.  Sorry if I was not clear in my original post.  I want to understand why this happened.

Comment: Maybe someone else can sleuth in the code, but I'm fairly positive this is some wonky (though sensible) type conversion. The POSIX origin is 1970-01-01, so relative to that 'today' has the int64 representation of `1617148800000000000` nanoseconds, or 51.279 years. So when you add 'today' as a timestamp to a datetime64[ns] it likely decides to add that big integer to the datetime64[ns] (because what else would it do?)

Comment: So the big question is - how, when using a Timedelta, to avoid this issue?  I answered my own question below by using `to_timestamp` instead of `to_timedelta`.  But curious to know if this can be done using `to_timedelta`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was easy, and staring me in the face.

The offending code:

```
s = pd.to_timedelta(df.start_time).shift(-1).sub(pd.offsets.Second(1))
```

The **correct** way to create an end_time off of a timestamp type series/column:

```
s = pd.to_timestamp(df.start_time).shift(-1).sub(pd.offsets.Second(1))
```